# Custom UITableviewCell will not set label

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with my custom tableview cell. When I want to put text on my labels, it doesn't change. This is how my code looks like.

my NieuwsTableViewCell.h

```
@interface NieuwsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *topic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *omschrijving;

@end
```

my NieuwsTAbleViewCell.m

```
@implementation NieuwsTableViewCell
@synthesize topic;
@synthesize omschrijving;
```

and my firstViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NieuwsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NieuwsTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
            NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.topic.text = @"Stef";
            cell.omschrijving.text = [info objectForKey:@"Nie_omschrijving"];
            NSLog(@"voorlopige test");


            cell = (NieuwsTableViewCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're setting the text property inside the if (!cell) block. That block will only be called few times to create the reusable objects. To put it in a simple way move the cell.*.text = part outside of the if (!cell) block. Here's a complete code JIC

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NieuwsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NieuwsTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {   
            cell = (NieuwsTableViewCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }
                NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell.topic.text = @"Stef";
            cell.omschrijving.text = [info objectForKey:@"Nie_omschrijving"];
            NSLog(@"voorlopige test");

    return cell;
}
```